# How to build a literal array in Google Sheets using a range of cells?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'd like to build an array literal from a range. In this toy example, the range would be A1:A4:

[image]

Basically, column A could have any number of arbitrary values (spreadsheet ids, for example) and I want to apply some operation involving another cell (in this case B1) without having to type `={A1+$B$1;A2+$B$1;A3+$B$1;A4+$B$1}`

The actual operation is not simply addition, but something like this:

```
QUERY({
      IMPORTRANGE(A1,$B$1),
      arrayrange(if(len(IMPORTRANGE(A1,$B$1)), Sheet2!B2, ""))
    }, Sheet2!F2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your simplified post example (shown in your attached image), this would be the approach I'd go with in C1:

`=ArrayFormula(B1+FILTER(A:A,A:A<>""))`

As for your second example (`QUERY`...), since I don't know your end goal, your layout, your data or your data types, I can't really comment on that.

Comment: Fair enough. Maybe I oversimplified. My end goal is to importrange() from a list of spreadsheets and combine them into a single table. Column A is a list of spreadsheet ids, column B is the name of each spreadsheet (I'm using this trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64355165/355567)

Comment: Again, there is little I or anyone else will be able to tell you if we can't access the same sheets and data you are accessing. It's like calling a mechanic and saying, "My car is making a weird noise, like 'krch-krch-krch.' I can't tell you what make or model it is, and I can't bring it in for you to look at; but what's wrong with it and how can I fix it?" I say this only half-jokingly, as it's a fairly accurate analogy.